# $\sum\frac{k^{k/2}}{k!}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the following series converge or diverge?

$\sum\frac{k^{k/2}}{k!}$

I did the ratio test $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

I did

$\frac{(k+1)^{(k+1)/2}}{(k+1)!}$ $\frac{k!}{k^{k/2}}$

Then I simplified

$\frac{(k+1)(k+1)^{k/2}}{(k+1)(k^{k/2})}$

I then got
$k\rightarrow\infty$

$(\frac{k+1}{k})^{k/2}$

$\sqrt{e}$>1 So would the serie diverge.

Comment: You made a mistake in the simplification. You miss a $\sqrt{k+1}$ at the denominator.

Comment: Use parentheses where needed! E.g. $k+1/2\neq (k+1)/2$ and $an+1\neq a_{n+1}$. We have to be a little more careful when dealing with these kinds of things.

Comment: Also, while it may not be allowed for a problem like this, Sterling's approximation is the hammer: $a_k = \frac{k^{k/2}}{k!}$ $\approx \frac{(e^k)(k^{k/2})}{(k^k)(k^{1/2})}$ $\approx k^{-1/2}\frac {e^k}{k^{k/2}}$ $\approx k^{-1/2}\left(\frac{e^2}{k}\right)^{k/2}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{(k+1)^{(k+1)/2}}{(k+1)!}\cdot \frac{k!}{k^{k/2}}= \frac{(k+1)(k+1)^{(k-1)/2}}{(k+1)k^{k/2}} = \frac{(k+1)^{(k-1)/2}}{k^{k/2}} $$

Alternatively, we have $$\frac{(k+1)^{(k+1)/2}}{(k+1)!}\cdot \frac{k!}{k^{k/2}} = \frac{\sqrt{k+1}\cdot (k+1)^{k/2}}{(k+1)k^{k/2}}= \dfrac 1{\sqrt{k+1}}\cdot \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{k/2}$$

Comment: Hmm the part I am not sure if the numerator when you have have (k+1)^(k+1)/2 how did you factor it to (k+1)(K+1)^(k-1)/2

Comment: Notice that $(k-1)/2 + 1 = (k+1)/2$.

Comment: so can I write $(k+1)(k+1)^(k)$

Comment: @Fernando Multiply out $$(k + 1)\cdot(k+1)^{(k-1)/2} = (k+1)^{1+\frac{k-1}2} = (k+1)^{(k+1)/2}$$  Recall that $a\cdot a^n = a^{n+1}$. Here, $a = (k+1)$

Comment: Multiplying out I get $k^2+2k+1$

Comment: I think I see it now

Comment: So would I simplify one more time to get the the limit of k at infinity

Comment: Thanks for the help I think I will have to practice simplifying more simplification to solve these type of problem

Comment: @amWhy: Nice discussion and alternate method! Looks like you are well on your way to your goal! :-) +1